# Facebook Graph APi doesn't give back comments written by page itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following problem while getting the comments for a rating from Facebook.

Lets say my info is: 
ratingId = '1234'
pageToken = 'abcd'

I have a rating for my page where I replied once using the page account itself and once using my personal account (aka the admin)

If I make a request to
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/1234/comments?access_token=abcd

It gives me back a response that only shows the comment from my personal account. For some reason Facebook stripped out the comment that was posted as the page itself.

**Additional Information**
I also let some other people add comments to this rating. They also don't show up via the api. The Facebook documentation clearly states that normally if the post is public, it's comments are also public. I checked my rating's visibility and it is set to public.

Does anyone know why this is or how to get all the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can get informations in this page "https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/".

> Additionally, other users' profile information and comments will not be returned when accessing user posts, photos, albums, videos, likes, and reactions unless authorized by those users. These changes are effective immediately for new apps. Apps created before May 1, 2018 will continue to have access to this data until May 24, 2018.